# offsetWidth returns wrong width in css animated block under Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, offsetwidth

I'm trying to make a kind of "news bar" on a web page.
The bar use a CSS animation, and the text content is refreshed on each iteration using ajax to retrieve data from an RSS feed.

My problem is that the content length may vary, so I want to set the size of the font used to display the text small enough to display all the content.

I then use this function to resize the text content:

`function resize(content /*content div*/, maxHeight/*bar height*/, maxWidth /*bar width*/) {
    content.parentNode.style.fontSize = maxHeight + 'px';
    var totalwidth = content.offsetWidth;
    if (totalwidth > maxWidth) {
        content.parentNode.style.fontSize = (maxHeight * maxWidth / totalwidth) + 'px';
    }
}`

It sometimes works on first iteration, but after it returns totally wrong values (like 36) for totalWidth.
If I put a breakpoint on the 'if' line the debugger display a coherent value (like 4320) for content.offsetWidth.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.
I have to set the content as "inline-block".
If content display is set as "block" its offsetWidth vary with the css animation.